# Variation of strategy pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I'm using the strategy pattern to parse files of different formats.

Each strategy returns a list of strings parsed from the file. Now a requirement has been introduced to return some more data from one of the file types, so an update is required to one of the strategy's. Is there a common practice to achieve this ? I could store the extra data in a Future but I think this is overkill ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution I have come up with is to return a List of custom object types which store the extra parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new interface that inherits from the base strategy interface, exposing the new data you require. Then your concrete strategy implementation for the particular file would implement the extended interface.

When a concrete strategy class is selected and executed for any given file, you could check if it implements the extended interface and if so process the extra data accordingly.

The benefits of doing it this way are that you can actually write a data contract in your extended interface rather than having a free-form list of extra parameters. Also, the interface is reusable in other strategies if necessary.

The drawback is that if many other strategies are likely to depart from the common one you can end up with a big interface structure.